# Tips on making classic brick and plywood shelves

Tags: shelving

Moving into a new apartment in a couple weeks and I'm planning on making the classic brick and plywood shelves to put books and stuff. Any tips for me? Do I have to have it secured to a wall?

Comment: Do you mean a couple bricks stacked, with plywood running on top, then more bricks stacked, etc? Do you happen to have a bunch of bricks laying around? If not, Ikea, Walmart, home improvement stores, etc etc, all have pretty cheap shelves..

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I mean. I've got some extra bricks at home that I would be willing to bring up and use.

Comment: don't think I ever hear "brick and plywood" called "classic" before :)

Comment: @warren - classic would be beer crates, brick and plywood is a bit Yuppie

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Brick-and-board shelves are more of a makeshift, anything-goes project. However:

Securing the shelving to the wall is a good idea, especially in an earthquake-prone area.

Putting the bricks all in **vertical lines** will stop the boards from bending as much.

**Cinder blocks** are a good choice, as the stacks for bricks can topple.

Comment: thanks for the info. found some other stuff online. this will be fun to make :)