# What should I do with abandoned cinder blocks?

Tags: outdoor, cinderblock

I recently moved to my first home (with a modest yard). The previous owners left behind about 20 cinder blocks. I'd like to build something constructive with them in lieu of discarding them. Any suggestions?

I was thinking about a BBQ smoker. Is that possible with cinder blocks?

Any ideas or useful links will be much appreciated.

Comment: [Shelves](http://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/5495/tips-on-making-classic-brick-and-plywood-shelves)?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on your location, build a planter. This included the base and the wall surrounding it. You could do a traditional rectangle or something modern like these...

http://pocketgrow.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/HLIC/8ba626a0e2155abfa3bd213bdbba202e.jpg
[image]

Comment: where'd you get these photos from? They're great.

Answer (score 4):

You could build an outdoor fire pit.  Be sure to check with your local fire regulations first; depending on your location, the fire pit might not be allowed, or there might be restrictions on when you are allowed to use it.

Answer (score 1):

You could make a small seating area with benches made from cinder blocks and blocks for side tables; it'll be nicer if you top the cinder block structures with something comfortable to sit on.

A quick web search turned up:

1. [cinder block furniture projects](http://www.ehow.com/list_6769348_cinder-block-shelf-furniture-projects.html),
2. [hand make outdoor furniture](http://www.ehow.com/how_7789830_hand-make-outdoor-furniture.html)

A smoker might work, but the blocks are very porous; you're going to build up smoke in the walls, and you're going to have a hell of a time sealing the gaps between.

Comment: Thanks for all that useful info. I am finding conflicting info about the use of cinder blocks for a smoker; what you're saying makes sense. There's something compellingly postindustrial about using the cinder blocks for indoor furniture. Will have to float that idea with the wifey. :)